# 'Srch' is undefined Shareponit View

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jslink

I have a bug in JavaScript,

> '*Srch' is undefined 
>   in file sp.ui.listsearchbox.js, Line: 1, Column: 5673*

this bug there is only on view, and I don't have any ideas how fixed this bug.

Maybe someone can help me ?